# Java - Selenium - Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 94, so returning the closest version found: 93

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Selenium and I'm having an error about CDP versions when running my code.
This is my code. It's simple, aiming to log in into some web page. The driver opens, fills the email and password but when reaching the button, the driver closes. Even if I set another wait for ten minutes after the button.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/my/chromedriver");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            try {
                driver.get("https://someweb.com/");
                driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("anemail@email.com");
                driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("randomPass");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            } finally {
                driver.quit();
            }

        }
```

I get the following warning in my log

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed0b1c69bb4e51ea0252171854915-refs/branch-heads/4606@{#1204}) on port 44814
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
oct 06, 2021 9:45:02 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
oct 06, 2021 9:45:02 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 94, so returning the closest version found: 93
oct 06, 2021 9:45:02 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 94 of 93

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And I have the following dependencies in my pom

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have no idea why the driver exits so suddenly. Chrome and ChromeDriver version is 94.0.4606.61. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per `Selenium` documentation,

- The version `v4.0.0-rc-1` supports `CDP` versions: `85`, `92`, `93`.

But you are using `94` version of `Chrome` and `ChromeDriver`. So please update your dependencies to latest version
`v4.0.0-rc-2`

**Dependency**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Reference**: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: everytime we should update POM with latest selenium ? @Nandan A

Comment: No I guess. That was selenium beta version but if you use latest one it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding the specific dependency that directly supports the webdriver and browser I am using. I am using v113 of chrome, so I added the selenium-devtools-v113 dependency and that got rid of all the warnings.
[Get the version you need from the link here.](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=Selenium%20DevTools)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v113</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And for the sl4j warning (which I see in the question), I added the below dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

your test script is completed thats y it closes the driver, simply put Thread.Sleep(10000) below this line driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="login-form"]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
to see the screen after driver performed the click option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).